# Add custom video at Fotorama - Magento 2 Product Page

Tags: javascript, php, magento2, fotorama

I am trying to add a custom video to Fotorama slider at *Product Page* that I have uploaded at the storage of my server on this path: `pub/media/videos`.

I have already tried this code, but didn't work as I expected...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        $(document).on('gallery:loaded', function () {
            var $fotorama = jQuery('div.gallery-placeholder > div.fotorama');
            var fotorama = $fotorama.data('fotorama');
            $fotorama.on('fotorama:load', function fotorama_onLoad(e, fotorama, extra) {
                if (extra.frame.type === 'iframe') {
                    extra.frame.$stageFrame.html('<iframe align="middle" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="' + extra.frame.src + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>');
                }
            });
            fotorama.push({
                thumb: 'pub/media/videos/product/video1.mp4',
                'src': 'pub/media/videos/product/video1.mp4',
                type: 'iframe',
                caption: '<set your caption>'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to take the [tour] and read [ask]. Posting some code and saying it "didn't work as expected" isn't enough to get a good answer to your question. Can you please [edit] your question and add details of exactly what you do want your code to do, and explain what results you are getting from your code, so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fork of fotorama files with an easy usage of HTML5 videos. Here is a functional example of how to use my update. This is only functional for MP4 videos. I modified Fotorama js for this situation that I also face before.

For more information, and README file, you can check it in [GitHub](https://github.com/megacarlossm/fotorama-mcsms/blob/master/README.md).

```js
$('.fotorama').fotorama();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/megacarlossm/fotorama-mcsms/fotorama-mcsm.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="fotorama" data-width="100%" data-maxheight="150px" data-nav="thumbs" data-allowfullscreen="true" data-loop="true" data-arrows="always" data-click="true" data-shadows="true">
  
    <a data-thumb="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/tihiychelovek/tihiychelovek1907/tihiychelovek190700099/130611355-cobweb-on-a-dark-background-dark-background.jpg?ver=6" href="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" data-type="video/mp4"></a>
    
    <a data-thumb="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/1c/bb/66/1cbb664a37bcb91ecbe40fae5ec07e11.jpg" href="https://www.prontus.cl/prontusPlayer4/samples/video/PIPER_SHORT_FILM_720p.mp4" data-type="video/mp4"></a>
    
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/megacarlossm/fotorama-mcsms/fotorama-mcsm.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding via JavaScript

```
let video = {
    thumbnail: thumbnail,
    url: url
};
$.when(getGallery()).then(function (result) {
    result.fotorama.data.push({
        videoUrl: video.url,
        src: video.url,
        img: video.thumbnail,
        isMain: false,
        thumb: video.thumbnail,
        type: 'video'
    });
}, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
});
getGallery: function () {
    let dfd = $.Deferred();
    let timer = setInterval(function () {
        let gallery = $('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]').data('gallery');
        if (typeof gallery != 'undefined') {
            clearInterval(timer);
            dfd.resolve(gallery);
        }
    }, 500);
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Adding via module with PHP

File app/code/My/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery">
        <plugin name="insertProductVideo" type="My\Module\Plugin\Gallery\Gallery" sortOrder="5"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

File app/code/My/Module/Plugin/Gallery/Gallery.php

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Plugin\Gallery;
class Gallery
{
    public function afterGetGalleryImagesJson(ImageGallery $subject, $result)
    {
$product = $subject->getProduct();
if ($product->getVideoPath()) {
        $imagesSettings = \Zend_Json::decode($result);
        $imagesSettings[] = [
                'caption' => '',
        'position' => count($imagesSettings) -1,
        'isMain' => false,
        'type' => 'video',
        'videoUrl' => $product->getVideoPath(), // path to product video like /pub/media/video/800x800_8bit_MP4_H264_quality50.mp4
        'src' => $product->getVideoPath(), // path to product video like /pub/media/video/800x800_8bit_MP4_H264_quality50.mp4
        'img' => $product->getPlaceholder(), // path to video placeholder image like /pub/media/placeholder/800x800_placeholder.png
        'thumb' => $product->getPlaceholder(), // path to video placeholder image like /pub/media/placeholder/800x800_placeholder.png
        ];
        $result = \Zend_Json::encode($imagesSettings);
        }
return $result;
    }
}
```